# Implementation of a NodeJs api

Tags: node.js, api, rest

I have a small problem for the production of a website on O2switch. The frontend was developed in VueJs. I didn't have any problem to put it online. The backend is an api rest made in NodeJs. I installed the NodeJs application on the host and put the API files in a/api/ folder at the root of the FTP.

Locally, by running the front and back servers and the DB everything is communicating well. The DB is fed from the front through the API.

But in the online version, the return of the requests made with Axios is an HTML page and not the expected JSON. Any idea of the problem?

Comment: Did you start the nodejs application? Are node endpoints exposed to the public?

Comment: I think. The return of the API is 200. What do you call endpoint?

Comment: You can try to add a user. I made sure that the api feedback is displayed : https://urlz.fr/lxj2

Comment: You can send the http request since postman if it's your question

Comment: Here is the response of the API : { "data": "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\"><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"></head><body><noscript><strong>We're sorry but Titre du site doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong></noscript><div id=\"app\"><app></app></div><script src=\"/js/chunk-vendors.338c5f9c.js\"></script></body></html>",

Comment: "status": 200, "statusText": "OK", "headers": { "connection": "keep-alive", "content-encoding": "gzip", "content-type": "text/html", "date": "... 21:58:26 GMT", "last-modified": "... 21:58:07 GMT", "server": "o2switch-...", "transfer-encoding": "chunked", "vary": "Accept-Encoding" },"config": { "url": "[link]http://example.com/api/auth/login[/link]", "method": "post", "data": "{\"email\":\"test@free.fr\",\"password\":\"1234\"}", "headers": { "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",

Comment: "Content-Type": "application/json" }, "transformRequest": [ null ], "transformResponse": [ null ], "timeout": 0, "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN", "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN", "maxContentLength": -1, "maxBodyLength": -1, "transitional": { "silentJSONParsing": true, "forcedJSONParsing": true, "clarifyTimeoutError": false } }, "request": {} }